# PHP not redirecting to required page

Tags: php, mysql, window.location

My add_comment.php has a input type button with value "cancel" its not redirecting the user back to the post on which he wants to comment if he press cancel .My add comment button however works perfectly .Please advise.

```
<?php  

 require_once 'app/helper.php';  
session_name('mypaperplane');
session_start();

 if (!verify_client()) {

    header('location: signin.php');
}

 $title='Add new comment';  
 $error="";

 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


     $comments = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'comment', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
     $comments = trim($comments);
     $post_id  = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );
     $post_id  = trim( $post_id );

    if (! $comments) {
         $error='*Comment field is required';

 }else{

     $com_link = mysqli_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PWD, MYSQL_DB);
     $uid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
     $post_id = mysqli_real_escape_string( $com_link, $post_id );
     $comments = mysqli_real_escape_string( $com_link, $comments );
     $comsql="INSERT INTO comments VALUES('',$post_id,$uid,'$comments', NOW())";
     $comresult = mysqli_query($com_link,$comsql);

     if($comresult && mysqli_affected_rows($com_link)>0){

        header("location:readMore.php?id=$post_id");
     }else{

         header("location:readMore.php?id=$post_id");
     }
 }
 }
 ?>

 <div class="content">  

 <?php include'tpl/header.php'; ?>

     <form name="comment" method="post">
         <label for="comment">Comment here:</label><br><br>
         <textarea rows="15"  cols="15" name="comment" id="comment"></textarea><br><br>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add comment" onclick="window.location='readMore.php?id= <?= $post['id']; ?>';">  
         <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location.href='readMore.php?id=$post_id'"><br><br>
         <span class="errorB"><?= $error; ?></span>

 </form>
       <?php include'tpl/footer.php'; ?>
             </div>
```

Comment: I tried its not leting me to post it

Comment: What is it saying?

Comment: when i try to edit? that its not properly formated

Comment: I am trying its still writing the same issue ...very confusing

Comment: I'd need an account for that, try eval.in or https://pastebin.com/.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/gdavrCLA

Comment: You need to put `$post_id` in `PHP` blocks and echo it. The code went into the question for me. Not sure what you were encountering, might want to post that on https://meta.stackexchange.com/ if it is persistent for you.

Comment: Ok thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You need to put short tags around $post_id

```
'readMore.php?id=<?= $post_id ?>'
```

Comment: when I put short tags a cancel button not responding at all its just stay on the same page and not redirects you att all